# Converting a list of dict to a list of a specific value

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'd like to know the most elegant (and performant?) pattern to replace what I often code as:

```
names = []
for person in persons:
    names.append(person.GetName())
```

I write this because it's how I'd write it in JavaScript, and I don't know any better. But I imagine there's something I can do with list comprehensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = [person.GetName() for person in persons]
```

Comment: Thanks - that's the one. What should I change the title of this question to as I don't think I've worded it well?

Comment: Something like "More elegant/pythonic way to populate a list?".

Answer (score 1):

`names = [person.GetName() for person in persons]`